# Natural transformation gives unique commutative diagram involving direct limits

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

The following is taken from page 38 in [A Term of Commutative Algebra](http://web.mit.edu/18.705/www/13Ed.pdf) by Altman and Kleiman. $\mathcal{C}$ and $\Lambda$ are categories, $\lambda\mapsto M_\lambda$ and $\lambda\mapsto N_\lambda$ are functors from $\Lambda$ to $\mathcal{C}$.

> Assume $\mathcal{C}$ has direct limits indexed by $\Lambda$. Then, given a natural transformation from $\lambda \mapsto M_{\lambda}$ to $\lambda \mapsto N_{\lambda}$ , universality yields unique commutative diagrams
>
> $$\require{AMScd}
> \begin{CD}
> M_\lambda @>>> \varinjlim M_\lambda\\
> @VVV @VVV \\
> N_\lambda @>>> \varinjlim N_\lambda
> \end{CD}$$

What exactly is this universality? And how does it yield unique commutative diagrams?

Comment: It's the notion of "universal" defined on the previous page. As it states in the following paragraphs, the collection of commutative diagrams is just the unit of an adjunction, namely the adjunction characterizing colimits. The diagrams are actually naturality squares for the unit.

Comment: @DerekElkins Thank you. But I don't see how this definiton is to be used. Could you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The universality here is the definition of direct limit.

Remember that the direct limit is an object $\varinjlim N$ together with a family of maps $\beta_\lambda :  N_\lambda\to \varinjlim N$ (called "insertions" in your notes) that commutes with the "transition maps" of $N$; and a natural transformation $\gamma:M\to N$ is a family of maps $\gamma_\lambda:M_\lambda\to N_\lambda$ that commute with the "transition maps" of $M$ and $N$. So composing them gives you family of maps $\beta_\lambda\circ \gamma_\lambda :M_\lambda\to \varinjlim N$ that commutes with the transition maps. Then the universal property defining $\varinjlim M$ tells you that this family of maps must factor uniquely through the insertions $\alpha_\lambda:M_\lambda\to \varinjlim M$, or in other words, that there must be a unique map $\hat{\gamma}:\varinjlim M\to \varinjlim N$ (the right-hand vertical map in your diagram) such that $\hat{\gamma}\circ \alpha_\lambda=\beta_\lambda\circ \gamma_\lambda$ for all $\lambda$ (this is the commutativity of the diagram in your question).

Comment: Thank you. I get there if I use the diagram given after the definition of direct limits, but how does this diagram follow from the definition? I don't really know what $\mathcal{C}$ universal means.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood your question, the diagram after the definition of direct limit is actually part of the definition; it is exactly what "universal among objects $P$ equipped...maps of $\Lambda$" means. See also the explanation given by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(category_theory)#Colimits) (but be aware that the page "Direct limit" is about a special case of the one defined in your notes).

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks!

Comment: One more thing (I hope it's okay to take it here): Do the insertions commute with all the transitions maps with the same domain and codomain? Or could there be different insertions for different transition maps even if the transition maps have the same (co)domain?

Comment: The insertions are indexed by the objects of $\Lambda$; so if two transition maps have the same domain and codomain because the corresponding maps in $\Lambda$ do, then they commute with the same insertions. On the other hand, if they have the same domains and codomains only because $M$ identifies some objects of $\Lambda$, then you have different insertions. For example, given a pair of arrows in $\mathcal{C}$ with the same domain and codomain, you would one insertion for the codomain when taking their coequalizer, but two when taking their pushout.